# How can my ember addon tell the host app to include specific assets?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I have a library that has some static assets -- PNGs, SVGs, WOFFs -- and a single Sass file. The library looks something like

```
- sass/
  - my-library/
    - all.scss
- images/
  - my-libarary/
    - logo.png
```

I want to enhance this project to make it work with Ember apps that use ember-cli. The goal is to have the host app end up with

```
- dist/
  - assets/
    - my-library/
      - all.css
      - logo.png
```

Here's what I tried:

```
treeFor: function(type) {
  if (type !== 'styles') { return; }
  var sass = require('broccoli-sass');
  var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
  var funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

  var asCss = sass(
    [ path.join(absolutePathToMyLibrary, 'sass') ],
    'my-library/all.scss',
    'my-library/all.css'
  ];

  // Hoping to compile sass/my-library/all.scss to assets/my-library/all.css
  var css = funnel(asCss, {
    files: [ 'my-library/all.scss' ],
    destDir: 'assets'
  });

  // Hoping to copy images/my-library/* to assets/my-library/*
  var images = funnel(path.join(absolutePathToMyLibrary, 'images'), {
    destDir: 'assets'
  });

  return mergeTrees(css, images);
}
```

But I get

`ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/me/Code/my-app/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-0WdzK7Cd.tmp/my-library/'`

when I run `ember build`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple: I want `treeFor('public')`, not `treeFor('styles')`. The former adds arbitrary assets to the build. The latter is specific to the handling of `app/styles`.